# Chrome (webkit?) not displaying images correctly in a slideshow

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, slideshow

I've read quite some posts about webkit browsers having issues with images. I couldn't find a post and thus an answer for the one I'm about to explain.

I created a home-made slideshow using jQuery that basically places all the images next to each other on a row and I then play with a mask element (overflow: hidden) and the margin-left property to select which one is to be displayed. I didn't reinvent the wheel...

On FF, Opera and even IE, it works like a charm! But I have no luck on Chrome (I didn't test Safari) : the first image shows ok but when the sliding effect kicks in, 20px-ish of the first slide remains at the top of the slideshow and overlay the second slide. If I carry on sliding, the first slide part remains as an overlay on the following slides. The images don't refresh ok on Chrome which makes the whole slideshow look rubbish.

I tried to play with the images css properties after the sliding effect to kind of force the container to refresh its content but again, no luck.

Does anybody have an idea on how to work that out?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the fix...

As I said, trying to force the container to refresh its content using some different css properties didn't work.
What worked though was to add a span to the container, that's it... At the time of the issue, my container only had images in it and a map. I added a span (out of luck) and it worked straight away!

I can only assume why adding a span makes the whole container behave ok. I guess it is kind of the same than the "hasLayout" property IE6 used to throw at geeks. It couldn't render the element properly until it had an element that had a consistency (height, width ... set with a value).

Anyway, I hope this will help and yes, I did dare to compare Chrome to IE6... ;-)

Good day